# PIC program not working

Tags: automation, microcontroller, pic

My first useful project with pic which was to make a smart home automation system with 2 lasers that are put at the entrance of a room and detects whether you are getting in or out according to which laser you cut first from the LDR so if you are getting in you cut the first laser then the second and vise versa and accordingly it turns the light on or off and it also counts how much people entered and turn the lights off after the last gets out, the code is not working whatever i try with it and IDK why the lights get on whenever i cut only 1 laser alone, code is written with MPLAB and compiled with XC8, mcu: pic16f877a

main.cpp:

```
#include "define.h"

int main(){
    int counter = 0;
    TRISB = 255;
    OPTION_REG = 0b01111111;
    TRISC = 0;
    PORTC = 0;

    while(1){
        if(laser1 == 1 && laser2 == 0 && counter == 0){
            for(int x = 0; x <= 3000; x++){
                if(laser2 == 1){
                    PORTCbits.RC0 = 1;
                    counter++;
                    x = 0;
                    break;
                }
                __delay_ms(1);
            }

        }else if(laser1 == 1 && laser2 == 0 && counter >= 1){
            for(int y = 0; y <= 3000; y++){
                if(laser2 == 1){
                    counter++;
                    y = 0;
                    break;
                }
                __delay_ms(1);
            }
        }else if(laser1 == 0 && laser2 == 1){
            for(int z = 0; z <= 3000; z++){
                if(laser1 == 1){
                    counter--;
                    z = 0;
                    if(counter == 0){
                        PORTCbits.RC0 = 0;
                    }else{
                        PORTCbits.RC0 = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                __delay_ms(1);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

define.h:

```
/* 
 * File:   define.h
 * Author: Fady
 *
 * Created on March 11, 2015, 10:51 PM
 */

#ifndef DEFINE_H
#define DEFINE_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


// PIC16F877A Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

#include <xc.h>

#define laser1 PORTBbits.RB0
#define laser2 PORTBbits.RB1
#define LED PORTCbits.RC0
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = XT        // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)


#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* DEFINE_H */
```

the circuit is a very simple one tho,:

where i only connected the led from PORTC pin 0 to ground and the 2 LDRs on pinb 1 & 2 in addition to power, of course, in vcc and MCLR and gnd and the 4MHz crystal

Comment: Can you provide some more info what does happen? Do the lights turn on at all, are you able to test debug in some form, does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: yup the led turns on when only any ldr of the two has laser falling on it without having any relation with the other

Comment: sorry forgot the header file will put it now

Comment: I haven't done a great deal of work with PIC programming but it seems to me you could do this a lot simpler which may help with debugging. Try this for your while loop: `while (1){ if (laser1 == 1 && laser2 == 0) { for (int x = 0; x <= 3000; x++) { if (laser2 == 1) { PORTCbits.RC0 = 1; counter++; break; } } } else if (laser1 == 0 && laser2 == 1) { for (int x = 0; x <= 3000; x++) { if (laser1 == 1) { counter--; if (counter == 0) { PORTCbits.RC0 = 0; } break; } } } }`

Comment: I suggest breaking the problem down into smaller parts. Try a simple case just to test functionality first. Such as if laser 1 is tripped turn the LED on, if it's tripped again turn the LED off. Then do the same thing with laser 2.  Just to be certain your I/O and the MCU is setup and functioning properly. Then make it more complicated from there.

Comment: @BinaryJudy That's a good startup process and important to do, however rather out of context of the question. Asking if the op has tested to make sure his' I/O and MCU is setup and functioning would have been better. Just a thought for future reference.

Comment: @CalebB: "rather out of context of the question". I wasn't answering the question, it was comment, and it was very related to the question considering the odd behavior, like when he says "IDK why the lights get on whenever i cut only 1 laser alone". Just asking if the I/O and MCU is setup and functioning correctly doesn't help the op.

Comment: @CalebB The hint for adding a comment says to ask for more info or suggest improvements, and avoid answering the question in a comment. I helped the op by **suggesting** how he/she can possibly narrow in on the problem, and/or improve his/her debugging skills. I don't know what you're problem is. I didn't do anything wrong, and there's nothing wrong with my comment. Maybe you're in the wrong place? If you say anything else, I'm not going to respond. I'm on here to help people, unlike you whom just wants to criticize other peoples helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

i tried messing in the code a bit, at last it worked i removed the else from the else if statements to be all if and it magically worked great,, here is the full code:

```
#include "define.h"

int main(){
    int counter = 0;
    TRISB = 255;
    OPTION_REG = 0b01111111;
    TRISC = 0;
    PORTC = 0;

    while(1){
        if(laser1 == 1 && laser2 == 0){
            for(int x = 0; x <= 3000; x++){
                if(laser2 == 1){
                    LED = 1;
                    counter++;
                    x = 0;
                    break;
                }
                __delay_ms(1);
            }

            __delay_ms(250);
        }
        if(laser1 == 0 && laser2 == 1){
            for(int x = 0; x <= 3000; x++){
                if(laser1 == 1){
                    counter--;
                    if(counter == 0){
                        LED = 0;
                    }
                    x = 0;
                    break;
                }
                __delay_ms(1);
            }
            __delay_ms(250);

        }

    }
}
```